# Save Excel file backup copy to SharePoint using VBA

Tags: vba

I understand that it's not possible to use .SaveCopyAs to SharePoint so I'm looking for a workround.  I want to save a copy of a file with the date appended and .bak extension.  I can do this to a local drive.  So I'm looking for code to open File Explorer so that the user can select the SharePoint folder to save the file in, using the string file name generated by the code.
Hope that's clear.

Comment: Hope the link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786792/vba-macro-to-save-to-sharepoint-with-dynamic-file-name and https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-copy-files-to-sharepoint-with-excel-vba.33083/

Comment: Appreciate the quick response - the Chandoo one doesn't quite hit the mark but the Stackoverflow link looks interesting.  Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Macro to Save to SharePoint with dynamic file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786792/vba-macro-to-save-to-sharepoint-with-dynamic-file-name)