# VBA: Save to sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, save-as

I am trying to build a macro that save excel file to sharepoint based on cell value.

I have two cells that:

*the sharepoint path is copied from Teams using copy link.

- "A1" = sharepoint path
- "A2" = file name

Below is the VBA that I used.
But whenever I run it, it will show this error.

> Run-time error '1004':
> Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Worksheet' failed

```
Sub filename_cellvalue()
Path1 = Range("A1").Value
myfilename = Range("A2").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path1 & myfilename & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

Thank you in an advance.

Comment: Maybe you can also include what values you have in `A1` and `A2` because that matters. Does `ActiveWorkbook` include any code? If so, you cannot save it as an XLSX.

Comment: `A1` contains the copied sharepoint link (for example: /www.sharepoint.com/:x:/...), while `A2` contains texts that will become the file name when saved. Right now, the `ActiveWorkbook` is test workbook with no other VBA code than above code.

Comment: Start by removing the possibility that getting values from the cells is the problem. Hard code it first and get that working. If that does not work either, than it has nothing to do with getting the values from the cells. It would mean your path is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786792/vba-macro-to-save-to-sharepoint-with-dynamic-file-name

Comment: Thanks, I will try to hard code it first. Oh yes, thats the first post I came across and tried to apply it.

Comment: Make sure `Path1` ends with, or `myfilename` starts with a folder separator e.g. `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a worksheet to another file location in SharePoint will only work if **ALL** the following are true:

1. The current user account has write access to the target location.
2. The active document source is inside the same SharePoint environment as the target.
3. The SharePoint environment does NOT block macro enabled files.
4. The file is being saved as a macro enabled file considering we're literally writing the macro to do the Save As.  It doesn't matter that there's no other code on the worksheet.  This is a macro and therefore the worksheet will have to be saved as such.

When all these conditions are met, the following should do the trick:

```
Public Sub SaveToSharePoint()
targetFile = Range("A1").Value
targetPath = Range("B1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetPath & targetFile & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```