VBA to save to Sharepoint
I have a workbook that has a command button to make a backup save. My employer wants it on our Teams and saved on SharePoint. I cannot figure out how to alter the code to work. Here is what the current code is that saves to the specified location:
Sub Backup_Save()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    folderPath = "C:\Art\Art A\"
    With wb.Sheets("Vessel Schedule")
        fileName = .Range("F2").Value & " - " & _
                   .Range("P1").Value & " - " & _
                   Format(Now(), "mm-dd hhmm ss") & ".xlsm"
    MsgBox "Workbook saved successfully!"
    End With
    wb.SaveCopyAs fileName:=folderPath & fileName
End Sub


How would I alter the code to save in the same manner as above but to SharePoint?.
Tried using the SharePoint location, but would not work. Tried several suggestions from similar posts, but unable to get it to work.

Have you verified all 4 of these conditions? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75459426/8422953

easy hack: sync your teams/sharepoint location with onedrive, and write to the local onedrive directory. Onedrive will then sync it over the next couple of minutes. If you want this to work for other users, your current solution is closer. You'll need to change folderpath to your sharepoint address (including directories) and a slash ('/) on the end.
